# Acess Compile error - user defined type not defined vba access

Tags: listview, ms-access, vba, activex

I am having this compile error in my Microsoft Access application. I recently started working on MS access. So I am new to code in VBA. I have an desktop application (Access 2003) in which list of companies need to be sorted once user click on the column header. It was working but once I click 'Compile', it is throwing me this error. If I comment out following code, my program does compile but sorting does not work. Please help.

```
Dim ListViews As New clsListViews
Private Sub lstVendorList_ColumnClick(ByVal ColumnHeader As Object)
   ListViews.SortColumns lstVendorList, ColumnHeader
End Sub
```

When I researched online. Many of people were talking about references. Under my references, I have checked

```
Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
Visual Basic For Applications
Microsoft Access 9.0 object library.
```

Comment: Where's `lstVendorList` coming from? Also, the compile error should be highlighting an identifier. Which one?

Comment: @Mat'sMug: lstVendorList is the list of the company/vendors I need to sort. The compiler highlights at first line. ( i.e. Dim ListViews As New clsListViews). Again, this is not my code and I was trying to work on something else but I got compile error because of listview.

Comment: Is there a `clsListViews` class module in your VBA project?

Comment: @Mat'sMug: It seems like lstVendorList is not dimmed yet.

Comment: That would be a runtime error, not a compile-time one. If `clsListViews` is highlighted and VBA says "I don't know what this is", you're probably missing that type. Verify that you have a class module with that exact name in your project, and that it can be `New`'d up.

Comment: No, there is not any module named clsListViews

Comment: Then that's what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim ListViews As New clsListViews
```

This instruction declares a module-level object variable named `ListViews`, of type `clsListViews`.

VBA looks everywhere it can for a class named `clsListViews` that it can create an instance of and assign that `ListViews` reference, and when it can't find it, it gives you the compile error you're seeing.

Make sure you only `New` up objects of types that exist. If it's not listed in IntelliSense/autocomplete when you type the space after `New`, it's probably not a legal type to use.

Comment: So, do I have to dim both ListViews and lstVendorList? When I  `Dim ListViews As ListBox`. It gave me 'Method or data member not found' and highlighted on 'SortColumns'. I am sorry if I am asking minor thing but I just started learning VBA.

Comment: I can't guess what you're trying to do. If you copied code from somewhere online, you need to understand it before you use it. That new error means a `ListBox` does not have a `SortColumns` member/method, so you can't call a method that doesn't exist.